# Possible to structure iOS app folder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I wonder if it's possible to structure my app's folder?

Right now I have every file under the root folder.

Can I make a new folder inside that one called VC and put all my VC files in it? Is there anything else I have to remember when if I reorganise my app files? eg file paths etc

Comment: Are you referring strictly to the file organization within Xcode's project navigator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can very well do that and in fact it is a good practice to organise your Xcode project navigator in similar folder structure as you have in your file system; it really helps.

All you need to do is to right click on your project file name in project navigator and select `New Group`.

[image]

This should then look like:

[image]

And then re-name it to whatever you want. You can then put your files in the correct group based on relevance. I would also advise to add them in similar folder in filesystem.

This is how it look like for me:

[image]

**PS: You do not need to remember anything like file path etc. Xcode does that for you once you link your file in your target.**

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if you want your file paths to match your Xcode project structure, there is a [program called `synx`](https://github.com/venmo/synx) which can automatically do this for you.  I find this very valuable.  I'm not always looking at my project in Xcode.  Sometimes I'm looking at it on Bitbucket/Github, etc.

Comment: Wow... if it does what you say... u deserve a pat on back from me :). Thanks @nhgrif for sharing this. I shall definitely evaluate this program/tool!

Comment: Indeed it does.  I haven't tried it in the case where I'm working in a .xcworkspace and have multiple projects underneath.  I'm not sure how nicely it will play in that scenario.  And it does say it might confuse your CocoaPods (but you just have to reinstall the pods after running `synx`).

Answer (score 1):

YES   you can do it by following this way :

1) open your folder project

2 ) create new folder by name VC

3 ) open xcode

4 ) drag and drop your vc folder to left side bar

5 ) check create group folder

6 ) uncheck copy .....

7 ) put your view controller on this folder